# Insert statement inside while loop in SQL

Tags: sql, loops, insert

I want to insert the resultant rows of a query into another table. How can I perform this? Kindly help.

To better understand my question I simply execute the following query where I want the value of columnA to be the value of the column of the next row of the select statement in each iteration.

```
while exists (Select columnA from tableA where SOMECONDITION)
begin
    insert into tableB(columnA,Value1,Value2)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply do an `INSERT` with `SELECT`:

```
insert into tableB select columnA, value1, value2 from tableA where SOMECONDITION
```

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things, you need just insert entire projection from another table as result of a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO tableB SELECT columnA, Value1, Value2 FROM tableA WHERE *SOMECONDITION*;
```

Comment: The select query does not return a single row ,and value1 ,value2 are not the columns of of tableA.